# How big would the lakes presented in the two pictures presented be in square mileage?

Tags: area

[image]

[image]

This question is being asked for the sake of a worldbuilding project.  The reason I posted two separate maps instead of just one is that in the second picture, Megalakes Chad and Congo look much bigger than on the first one.  How big would each and every one of those lakes be in square miles?

Comment: How is this question about math? Why don't you choose some of the countries on the map with similar area, and then look up the number on wikipedia?

Comment: @Andrei  One, because the measurement of area is math.  Two, because Wikipedia doesn't have ALL the information.